# How to populate the "Description" field for docker images in GCP Artifact Repository

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console, google-artifact-registry

I have pushed a docker image to an artifact repository in google cloud. When I go to the google cloud console Artifact Repository page, I see this:

[image]

When I click on the kebab menu on the right, I can edit the tags but I do not see an option to edit the Description. How do I add/edit the description?

Comment: I did find the same missing Description field when pushing test Docker images to my repository, and neither the documentation nor the API for Artifact Registry expose any option to interact with this field. You can report this issue to Google Cloud using the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/). You can use [this page](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#issue_reports) for reference when creating an issue.

Comment: I've come across this need to record some useful information that is not a tag.

Comment: There is an [open issue in the Google issue tracker here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/232434109). It was opened May 12, 2022 as a "feature request" with no recent updates. You can click the +1 in the top-right to let them know "I am impacted" and maybe increase the likelihood they look at this.